# Is there any end point to hit the Speed limit using Open Street Mapping in android?

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Is the any API available to get the Speed limit for the corresponding lat and log in Open Street Mapp like in Google API, https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?parameters&key=YOUR_API_KEY

If any one know plz post your suggestion,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Comment: hi scai.. does we require any API key as like in Google API  in ORM to track speed limit?

Comment: I have tried with Overpass API by hitting http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[maxspeed=*][bbox=12.25276,79.41432,12.25303,79.41486],but am getting empty response like below,                                                                                                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2016-07-22T06:01:02Z"/>

</osm>

Comment: No, you do not need an API key. If the result is empty then maybe there is no maxspeed information in OSM  available for this area.

Comment: The roads api corresponds more to software called everywhere else 'map matching' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching With such a software attaching speed values would be relative simple